# Mantain a div rotated when is hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this html code:

```
<div id="To-Top"> <img src="/to-top.png" alt="Volver Arriba" /></div>
```

This is the Css:

```
#To-Top { width: 30px; height: 28px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;
overflow:hidden;}
.rotado{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

// hide #back-top first
jQuery("#To-Top").hide();

// fade in #back-top
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
            jQuery('#To-Top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            jQuery('#To-Top').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    jQuery('#To-Top img').click(function () {
        jQuery('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });
});

});

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#To-Top").hover(function () {
            jQuery(this).addClass("rotado");
        }, function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("rotado");
        });
    });
```

For some reason works fine in both firefox a IE but in Chrome after perform ther animation the element returns to initial position even if hover is mantained.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Seems fine to me, tested with Chrome 33: http://jsbin.com/zebaq/1/edit

Comment: We are using in a joomla web, is this helps for solve the problem, thanks for the help.

Comment: Rather than using JQuery to add an class on hover, why not add your transform rules styles to `#to-top:hover`? You wouldn't need jQuery at all then.

Comment: Before of using jQuery I use CSS the problem matantains, i update the code, because the problem is the jQ code.Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a mees is webkit in early days xD the problem was solved adding

```
#To-Top { 
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thanks to all of you by your help :P

Answer (score 0):

`toggleClass` [can have two parameters](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1), one for `hover in`, other for `hover out`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#To-Top").hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass("rotado");
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("rotado");
    });
});
```

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJfer/1/)

Comment: This solution causes a problem, when need to mantain the div rotated only when in hover . My fault in title sorry.

Comment: Thanks, i update the whole js code , because doesn´t works, and the fact is that   your anwer is correct , i miss something in the code.Only happens in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MiguelR/8FEbZ/1/)

```
#To-Top { 
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30px; height: 28px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  }

.rotado {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

JS

```
// hide #back-top first
jQuery("#To-Top").hide();

 // fade in #back-top
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        jQuery('#To-Top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        jQuery('#To-Top').fadeOut();
    }
});

// scroll body to 0px on click
jQuery('#To-Top img').click(function () {
    jQuery('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
});

jQuery("#To-Top").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass("rotado");
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("rotado");
});
```

Comment: The problem persists, i use this solution before move to jQ , thanks for the help.